# XAML: accessing actual width and height

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a viewbox with an image inside:

```
<Viewbox MaxHeight="100" MaxWidth="100" x:Name="Scenario4ImageContainer2" Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
    <Image x:Name="Scenario4Image" PointerPressed="Scenario4Image_PointerPressed" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  />
</Viewbox>
```

I want to be able to grab the actual width/height values, but when I try this in the backend C#:

```
int w = (int)Scenario4ImageContainer.Width
```

I get an error saying the parameter is incorrect.

This goes away if I hardcode the width, but I want it to resize dynamically.

I also tried grabbing Scenario4ImageContainer.ActualWidth but this parameter was "incorrect" as well.

Comment: When did you try ActualWidth? Is control already active and laid out? Width is incorrect because it is NaN until you set it manually, but ActualWidth should not be NaN.

Comment: @ixSci: "Is control already active and laid out?" Hmm ... I'm referencing these parameters in the constructor. When explicitly setting width and height the values show up as expected.

Comment: try to reference it when it is laid out for sure. I believe **Loaded** event is a good candidate for it.

Comment: @ixSci(2): Good suggestion. I had to put it in the OnNavigatedTo() function because it gets called before Loaded. For some reason all dimensions are 0 in OnNavigated to as well. I tried checking the values in Loaded and for some reason my loaded doesn't get called ... even though I'm adding the delegate like this: "Loaded += Scenario4_Loaded;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On every draw I do a quick check to see if the container size has changed (with an initialization of 0 at the beginning to make sure it catches the first time).

```
if (containerWidth != Output.ActualWidth - 300)
{
    Scenario4ImageContainer.Width = Output.ActualWidth - 300;
    Scenario4ImageContainer.Height = Output.ActualHeight - 20;
    containerWidth = Output.ActualWidth - 300;
}
```

It works for the most part, but when the class gets navigated out and navigated back it has a problem for some reason. Probably unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

A while back I was trying to measure width of a string. You can try a similar mechanism to get dimensions.

http://invokeit.wordpress.com/2012/09/19/how-to-measure-rendered-string-dimensions-in-win8dev/

```
this.tb.FontSize = 20;
this.tb.Measire(new Size(400, 300)); // assuming that 400x300 is max size of textblock you want
double currentWidth = this.tb.DesiredSize.Width;
double currentHeight = this.tb.DesiredSize.Height;
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I've found the event you need to handle: you should handle **ImageOpened** event. It is because image is retrieved asynchronously and if try to handle any other event there is a good chance to not have image loaded at that time so actual size is zero